# Error when using user install pip2.7

Tags: python, pip

I built python 2.7.11 from source in my linux home directory and used its provided get-pip.py to install pip at a custom location ~/bin. But when I run ~/bin/pip2.7 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pip2.7", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip2.7')()
  File "/home/mnaymik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources    /__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/mnaymik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2568, in load_entry_point
raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group, name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip2.7') not found
```

~/bin/pip runs just fine though.

I imagine there is some conflict with the system installed python and my user installed one but I don;t know how to fix it.

Comment: Check with `which python` to see which version of python your system is using. If you get something other than your directory. Create an alias in your `.bashrc` with `alias python=/your/path/python`

Comment: which python just shows the one in my home dir. If I remove this dir from my path then /usr/bin/python shows up, this one is python 2.6.6

Comment: Then it doesn't seem to be a conflict with your system `python`

Comment: Remove the package `python-setuptools` if you have it, then run `sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools`. Another package that also might be in conflict is `python-pip`